# Cannot back to original working directory when running nodejs handlebars in windows batch file

Tags: node.js, batch-file, handlebars.js

1.bat - does as expected: go to the temp folder, do something, return to the original folder.  The current working directory (cwd) is the same before and after running 1.bat.

2.bat - when the 'do something' is running the handlebars nodejs package, even when it only prints something, **after exiting the batch file, cwd changes**.

3.bat - not using PUSHD, POPD.  Same as 2.bat.

When running the similar in shell scripts, cwd never changes.

The question: what is wrong?  How to go back to the original cwd?

```
REM  1.bat
PUSHD %CD%
CD /D %TEMP%
DIR
POPD
```

---

```
REM  2.bat
PUSHD %CD%
CD /D %TEMP%
handlebars --help
POPD
```

---

```
REM  3.bat
SET orgdir=%CD%
CD /D %TEMP%
handlebars --help
CD /D %orgdir%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you indicate, this works

```
REM  1.bat
PUSHD %CD%
CD /D %TEMP%
DIR
POPD
```

but it is not how this should be written.

- `pushd` works by saving the current active directory (to be later retrieved by the `popd`) and then change to the indicated one, changing the drive unit if needed and if necessary mapping a drive letter when changing to a UNC path.
- paths *should* be quoted to avoid problems with spaces or special characters

So, the code should be

```
REM  1.bat
PUSHD "%temp%"
DIR
POPD
```

Now, the problematic batch file *could* be

```
REM  2.bat
PUSHD "%temp%"
handlebars --help
POPD
```

but, if the original file didn't return to the previous active directory, this will also fail to do it.

Why? in windows `handlebars` command is a batch file. When a batch file invokes another one, the execution flow is transfered to the called file and does not return to the caller, so, the `popd` will not be executed.

To invoke a child batch file and get the execution flow return to the caller, you will need to use the `call` command

```
REM  2.bat
PUSHD "%temp%"
call handlebars --help
POPD
```

Another alternative *in this case* (if you don't need to end with changes in any environment variable nor continue executing commands in the caller) is to use the `setlocal` command. It saves a copy of the current environment to allow us to discard any change made to it when calling the `endlocal` command or when the batch context ends. This save operation includes the current active directory.

```
REM  2.bat
setlocal
cd /d "%temp%"
handlebars --help
```

Now, the execution flow does not return to the caller, but it is not needed. When the child batch file (`handlebars`) ends, the batch context is released and the changes to the environment after the `setlocal` are reverted.